# Having a function as an argument

Tags: c#, function

I am trying to make a new Timers class to aid with my learning of c#. How would I let an argument for a function be a function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's pretty simple. Just make the argument be some kind of `delegate` type, like `Action` or `Func`.

```
void PassAnAction(Action action)
{
    action(); // call the action
}

T PassAFunction<T>(Func<T> function)
{
    return function();
}
```

Comment: How would I use the pass an action? Say I wanted to show a Hello World message box.

Comment: @Michael: Something like this: `PassAnAction(() => ShowMessageBox("Hello world"))`. (I don't know what you're using for showing message boxes, but hopefully that gives you an idea.)

Answer (score 1):

```
public class MyTimer {
    private readonly Action _fireOnInterval;

    public MyTimer(Action fireOnInterval, TimeSpan interval, ...) {
        if (fireOnInterval == null) {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("fireOnInterval");
        }
        _fireOnInterval = fireOnInterval;
    }

    private void Fire() {
        _fireOnInterval();
    }
    ...
}
```

You can call it like this:

```
new MyTimer(() => MessageBox.Show("Elapsed"), TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5), ...)
```